# What does the model option in odoo xml mean?

Tags: odoo

I found this code in the odoo and the `options="{'model': 'crm.lead'}` confused me?

What does this mean? And when should I use it?

```
                    <field name="assignment_domain" string="Domain" widget="domain"
                        options="{'model': 'crm.lead'}"
                        attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('assignment_max', '=', 0), ('assignment_optout', '=', True)]}"/>
```

Comment: Options are bound to the used field wigdet. So if you don't get an answer, try to look into the widgets javascript code of the widget "domain".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Domain` field allows the user to construct a technical-prefix domain and see the selected records in real-time.

The model option is used to set the model the field must work with, the model and domain are used to fetch records.